# Wordpress Child Theme Enqueue and Dequeue and Localize

Tags: wordpress, enqueue

I am trying to enqueue an edited js file from my child theme and dequeue the original one from the parent. It should be simple, however, the parent theme is calling a function where all enqueues are made. I managed to enqueue it but not to dequeue. In addition, the original enqueue is followed by `wp_localize_script()` function.

**If I copy the whole function to my child it works, but I am looking for a cleaner and better way to achieve that.**

Here is how the original code is set up (Parent Theme):

In function.php this function is called

```
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpestate_scripts');
```

The `wpestate_scripts` function is found in another file, `css_js_include.php`

```
function wpestate_scripts() { 

// A bunch of files being enqueued and some variables being assigned

 wp_enqueue_script('wpestate_property', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ).'js/property.js',array('jquery','wpestate_control'), '1.0', true);   
        wp_localize_script('wpestate_property', 'property_vars', 
            array( 
                // Variables being localized
              )
        );

 }
```

I have already added `wp_dequeue_script('wpestate_property')` and `wp_deregister_script('wpestate_property')` to my child `function.php`. And it did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the function you're calling is fired after the script is enqueued by the parent. Typically this is done by adding a high integer value to the `$priority` argument for [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'modify_wpestate_scripts', 99 );
function modify_wpestate_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('wpestate_property');

    // Enqueue your custom script instead
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-wpestate_property', 'custom-wpep.js', [], '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script('custom-wpestate_property', 'property_vars', 
        array( 
            // Variables being localized
          )
    );
}
```

This adds it to the same action hook (`wp_enqueue_scripts`) as the parent function, but the priorty is set to `99` so it runs later (the default priority is `10`).

Comment: Great @Xhynk. How should I deal with the `wp_localize_script()` fucntion and vars?

Comment: I've updated the code - you can just enqueue your custom script under a custom handle and localize it

Comment: Great. I was expecting a way to avoid the copy and paste of `wp_localize_script()`. Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to "copy" programatically. Unless the parent theme stored the localization as a variable that you could access (it doesn't look it like, based on your example). Unfortunately since they're enqueued and localized at the same priorty there's not a way to intercept that localization either. You could _try_ changing the handle on your custom script to `wpestate_property`, but I don't think it will work